# Sum of even number using given range in R

Tags: r

I am trying to get sum of even numbers in R Using this code:

```
x<- c(80:100)
for(i in x) {
  if(i%%2==0) b<-append(b,i)
}
sum(b)
```

But I am not getting perfect answer.
When I print b after the if statement I get b as:

> [1] 100  80  82  84  86  88  90  92  94  96  98 100

why the first index is coming 100.

Comment: In your code you don't create (initialize) `b` before you use it in `append(b, i)`.. That's why the code above raises `b` not found error. You probably initialized it with 100 somewhere in your code.. That's where the leading 100 is from...

Answer (score 2):

Before the beginning of your loop, `b` probably already has a value of `100`. Make sure to initiate an empty `b` at the beginning.

```
x = c(80:100)
b = c()
for(i in x) {
    if(i %% 2 == 0){
        b = append(b, i)
    }
}
sum(b)
```

But you could just have done

```
sum(x[x %% 2 == 0])
```